# Node Express - Error when serving static content

Tags: node.js, express

I have some middleware which will redirect to a login page like so:

```
app.use('/login', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.accessToken){
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  next();
});
```

In some earlier code, when the server is starting up I have added my public directory as a static resource:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I see the login page appear, but its rendered incorrectly and I am seeing an error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This is reference the opening `<html>` tag in my login.html file. From other posts I have come across, this would seem to suggest a problem when using a template engine like Jade and using a raw html file which cant be processed, but I am not using jade in my setup, so I'm a bit confused.

Can someone help me understand what the problem may be here please?

**EDIT**

I have now tried redirecting to my login.html as per the comments, so I just have this right now:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.accessToken){
    res.redirect('/login.html');
  }
  next();
});
```

And already am serving static content from a public directory where my login page lives:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

But I now get a redirect loop error in the browser, and my server console throws an error from Express saying:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

**EDIT 2**

Managed to resolve this by using:

```
app.use('/login', function(req, res){
  res.status(401).sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/login.html'))
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.accessToken) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: it seems that /login should redirect to the static page public/login.html right ? You could use res.redirect('/login.html'); instead of res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html'); By the way are you  sure you are not declaring a template engine like ejs...

Comment: Yes it should, but using your approach will cause an infinite redirect loop

Comment: @mindparse, no it won't. Of course, you would have to add `app.use(express.static('public'));`, but once you redirect to `login.html`, it will load the .html file. There is no loop.

Comment: @mindparse why ? the redirection will just hit the static file login.html

Comment: Well I am getting a browser error now telling me there is a redirect loop. I do get an error in my server console too saying - `Can't set headers after they are sent.`